Is it possible to place Rigify's IK poles manually?
I've been rigging a simple human model with Rigify and I've encountered an issue where the limbs bend backwards. I know that the direction in which the limbs bend determines where the IK poles are placed, but my mesh has exaggerated proportions, causing the bones to be technically bent backwards. I can't adjust it recently without it being completely off from where the joint actually is.

Is there a way to just tell Rigify where I want the poles instead of Rigify doing it automatically? I tried to edit the poles in the rig after the rig generation and it just twisted the legs around when I applied it.

The knee joint needs to be bent slightly forward so that rigify knows which way the joint is going to bend. You could move the ankle end of the bone to the back of the heel to improve it slightly but basically your model isn't really modelled in a natural pose in the first place.

This question is actually not so much related to Rigify in particular, but rigging as a whole. We often model characters, or at least deform them afterward into a neutral "bind" pose (often the infamous A/T pose for humanoids), with relaxed articulations from head to toe. This is for multiple reasons, most of the ones that I know of come from the technicalities of rigging and skinning.
Having your model in a somewhat middle-ground state compared to the motions it can or should do, gives more changes of obtaining good deformations from automated skinning with minimal retouching required (I bet your hands shaped as a closed fist will have deformations and skinning issues).
Articulations from within a limb are often oriented the same way so to make rigging and animation easier and more predictable (you select a limb, rotate all on X, and all bends one direction instead of many different ones).
Blender's IK solver uses the bone chain's bending to know in which direction an IK chain should bend. Hence, in your case, it makes Rigify bend the knees backwards (but this is nothing specific to Rigify).
You could probably fix the IK issue just by moving the ankles, as @John Eason suggested, but not the rest.
So to be honest, if I were you, I would prefer putting the rigging phase on hold for now and spend a bit of time modifying the mesh to make it easier to work with as a rigged model.
Interesting documentation:

Rigify - Basic Usage - Blender 4.1 Manual
modeling - A pose or T pose? - Blender Stack Exchange
should i use T pose or A pose? - r/blenderhelp
Painting Weights and Skinning: A Straighforward Approach - Kiel Figgins

